How Can I Use Sharpnado Tabs in MAUI?
I’m working on a project using dotnet MAUI and trying to implement Sharpnado Tabs. I want to load pages (HomePage and ProfilePage) inside a ViewSwitcher but encounter some issues trying it. The error in question is: System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid generic arguments (Parameter 'typeArguments')'. I couldn't find any easy sample to practice it.
Here’s what I’ve tried:
HomeTabbedPage:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestingMAUI.Pages.HomeTabbedPage"
             xmlns:material="http://schemas.enisn-projects.io/dotnet/maui/uraniumui/material"
             xmlns:tabs="http://sharpnado.com"
             xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:TestingMAUI.Pages">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BottomTab" TargetType="tabs:BottomTabItem">
                <Setter Property="SelectedTabColor" Value="Gray" />
                <Setter Property="UnselectedLabelColor" Value="#00928A" />
                <Setter Property="LabelSize" Value="36" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansExtraBold" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="16,0" RowDefinitions="120,*,95">

        <tabs:ViewSwitcher x:Name="Switcher" Margin="0" Animate="True" Grid.RowSpan="3">
            <tabs:LazyView x:TypeArguments="Views:HomePage" />
            <tabs:LazyView x:TypeArguments="Views:ProfilePage" />
        </tabs:ViewSwitcher>


        <tabs:TabHostView Grid.Row="2" CornerRadius="30" IsSegmented="True" Orientation="Horizontal" TabType="Fixed">
            <tabs:BottomTabItem Style="{StaticResource BottomTab}" Label="M" />
        </tabs:TabHostView>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>

HomePage and ProfilePage have the same code (they have their respectives Classes):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestingMAUI.Pages.ProfilePage"
             Title="ProfilePage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>


"encounter some issues" is not a helpful description of the problem

sorry i wasn't clear enough. Here is the error that it throws: System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid generic arguments (Parameter 'typeArguments')'.

"HomePage and ProfilePage have the same code (they have their respectives Classes)"  are you sure the x:Class="" of ProfilePage and Hompage are set correctly?... if you copy pasted the xaml of one to another you need to set respective x:Class

I saw the problem is the tabs:ViewSwitcher/ element, when i delete it, the program show the bottom app bar, but if not, it throws the error i mentioned previously. I've checked both ProfilePage and HomePage and they are correct.

Have you checked Sharpnado Tabs sample Github

Yeah i've done it. But is a complex sample, there is so many files. Is there an easier way to implements it?

Maui do not have the native Sharpnado tabs. You can search the related resource on the GitHub.

I've already done it. But It doesn't explain how you can implement it. There is only a complex sample.
